# Remove Screen from navigation stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

#### App structure -

1. Home Screen - Have button navigate to shopping cart
2. ShoppingCart Screen - have button navigate to shop screen
3. Shop Screen - Have button navigate to shopping cart
   Using - react-native: 0.59.5, react-navigation: ^3.8.1

step 1 - go to shopping cart from home
step 2 - go to shop from shopping cart
step 3 - add some items to cart in shop
step 4 - go to shopping cart from shop - problem goes here.

in step 4 action show the previous screen of shoppingCart( that appeared screen at step 1 ).There are no new added items in the cart only have previous states.

I haven't any idea how to slolve this ? can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put event listener inside `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', payload => {
            console.log('[print action for test:]', payload);
            if (['Navigation/INIT', 'Navigation/NAVIGATE', 'Navigation/POP_TO_TOP'].includes(payload.action.type)) {
                this.doSomething()
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The current screen can be replaced using replace method

`navigation.replace(routeName, params, action)`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#replace

Comment: Awesome and handy! Did the job like a charm - thanks

Answer (score 0):

use [navigation-events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) to add onWillFocus/onDidFocus listener on shoppingCart and refresh the scene in that callback